# Winform DataGridView not show rows

Tags: winforms, datagridview

I bind the DataGridView with datasource (NOT NULL!)

```
AutoGenerateColumns = false
dgrList.Datasource = mySource;
```

I have a DataGridView with 4 columns (Design time).
"mySource" contain 3 rows, But the grid didn't make any rows. It's not the case which there are 3 "blank rows" with no-text, it show nothing, like the datasource is null (but not). When I using

```
foreach(var c in mySource){
   dgrList.Rows.add(new object[]....);
}
```

It's show 3 rows too.
There are no other statement set the datasource, except the one above

Comment: Code you showing here must work. Show more code. For example: maybe you clear `mySource` object after setting it to `DataSource` or something else.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the [DataPropertyName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.datapropertyname(v=vs.110).aspx) for the columns you have created, so that DataGridView knows which properties of the objects to display. E.g. if you have 2 columns (Name and Data):

```
dgrList.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
dgrList.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "Name";
dgrList.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "Data";

dgrList.DataSource = new List<object>() 
{ 
    new { Name = "A", Data = 1 }, 
    new { Name = "B", Data = 2 } 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

After you set the DataSource to the datagridview you need to call the DataBind method.

```
dgrList.Datasource = mySource;
dgrList.DataBind();
```